# How to merge 2 fields and find unique records from a JSON file using Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file which contains duplicate records and I need to send the unique records to another application. In order to get the unique records, first I need to merge JRNAL_NO & JRNAL_LINE fields separated a hyphen (ex: 655-1) and then use this key to identify the unique records. Is this possible to do via a python script?

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59jxF.png)

[Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcD6U.png)

Thank you,
John

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include it as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting) instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the expected results using the below script (thanks to some old posts in SO). I am new to Python, so if there are better ways of doing this, kindly suggest. Thanks.

```
import json
source = json.loads(input_var)
target = []
seen = set()

for record in source:
    name = record['JRNAL_NO'] + record['JRNAL_LINE']
    if name not in seen:
        seen.add(name)
        target.append(record)
del seen

output_var = json.dumps(target)
```